# How is the mapping between screen space and camera coordiante system in blender

Tags: camera, image

I was referring to this [link](https://ksimek.github.io/2012/08/14/decompose/) to understand how to decompose a projection matrix. It says that screen space can have a different coordinate system than the camera, even [scratchapixel](https://www.scratchapixel.com/lessons/3d-basic-rendering/get-started/gentle-introduction-to-computer-graphics-programming.html)  says the same. But I do not see any documentation in blender about it. How is the mapping from camera coordinate system to screen space in blender?
Is it as shown below, [image: map1] or [image: map2]

Or is it something different than both?

Comment: Please clarify what you mean by "screen space" and "camera space". How do you obtain those values? For example in shader nodes there's "Texture Coordinate: Camera", and "Texture Coordinate: **Window**"

Comment: @MarkusvonBroady screen space would be the coordinates obtained after performing projection from camera space. The scratchapixel link I provide explains it with visuals if that's helpful.

Comment: How is your problem related to Blender?

Comment: @MarkusvonBroady Each software can do this mapping according to their definition. I could not see any documentation how they do it in blender, I wanted to know how it is carried out in blender.

Comment: It is preferred here to try and explain your issue within the question instead of relying on external links, which might expire and make this question useless. Also it would be nice if we would not have to read through all the text for understanding. Is your question more or less if Blender sees images from bottom left to top right or the other way round?

Comment: The issue here is, this website is to ask questions about Blender. And the way you state your question, it's unrelated to Blender. Yes, such coordinate spaces (or similar) exist within Blender, but just like BSE is not the best place to ask a question about linear algebra, even though linear algebra is used by users and devs of Blender, asking about such concepts, is not best either. If you presented a real problem in Blender, solving which requires some explanation on differences between texture coordinates, then yes, it would be a valid question per this site rules.

Comment: @MarkusvonBroady I believe this is a valid question to ask here, as it pertains specifically as to how blender does this mapping.

Comment: @GordonBrinkmann the link was supposed to be an additional context. The image I gave provides the information regarding my question

Comment: *"I believe this is a valid question to ask here, as it pertains specifically as to how blender does this mapping."* - the reason why I think otherwise is that you couldn't answer my question on which coordinate systems in Blender do you mean specifically. If you clearly pointed to two coordinate systems in Blender (and I ask how you obtain them), then yes, this could be explained (and therefore the question doesn't need much to be a good question). But as it is phrased currently, we have to guess what you mean (and there's actually nothing to guess, you don't actually use those in Blender!)

Comment: @MarkusvonBroady Although I wrote an answer which was accepted, I totally agree with you on this matter.

Comment: @MarkusvonBroady I believe you are right, it seems that concept is not used in blender. It is still strange as it is part of generic computer graphics pipeline. Therefore I am deleting the question as it could be misleading

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The scratchapixel link might provide useful information, but I'm sorry it is too annoyingly much to read just to figure out what your question is. As I understand it you basically want to know if the coordinate system of an image viewed/rendered by the camera is going from bottom left to top right or top right to bottom left? Well, it is from bottom left to top right.

If you want to move something in compositing to the right, you have to move it in +X direction. Moving upwards is +Y direction. Also the coordinate system's origin is not in the center of the image but the bottom left as you can see in these examples:

Using a *Sun Beams* node in the *Compositor*, by default it is set to create sun beams starting at X = 0.5 and Y = 0.5, and in the screenshot you can see these beams starting from the center of the image, there is also a cross indicating the position if you have selected the node:

[image: image center]

Setting the starting point to X = 0.0 and Y = 0.0 moves it to the bottom left, X = 1.0 and Y = 1.0 is top right:

[image: origin at bottom left]

[image: top right]

Another way to see it with the rendered pixels is when you right-click with your mouse on the rendered image. While holding the right mouse button down, the status bar indicates the X and Y of where your cursor is positioned, going from X = 0 and Y = 0 in the bottom left corner to X = 1919 and Y = 1079 if you rendered an image with a size of 1920 × 1080 pixels:

[image: image pixels]

Also the 2D coordinate system of the *UV Editor* goes from bottom left (0, 0) to top right (1, 1):

[image: uv origin]

[image: uv top right]

If this is not what you are asking for, then I need more clarification in your question.

Comment: Thank you, this is what I was referring to, I believe that (0.5, 0.5) in your example refer to the screen space.

Comment: @ssuraj I do not believe (0.5, 0.5) refers to screen space, I actually do not understand what screen space is in this context. In your scratchapixel link the term "screen space" is used exactly once and is said to be used synonymous with "canvas", which is more or less the image plane. So the "screen space" is the rectangular area of the image between (0, 0) and (1, 1). Of course the "screen space/canvas" has a different coordinate system than the camera, because it's always 2D starting at one corner to the next, while the camera can be moved and rotated in the 3D space of the scene.

Comment: @ssuraj You're starting some sort or semantics discussion. Imagine that you asked »What is a difference between a "figure" and a "shape" in Blender?«. Upon our questioning where in the interface you see those terms you would say you don't, but those are terms common in software, and you wonder how it looks in Blender. Once someone assumes what you might mean, you ask »oh so is that what a "shape" is?« In the end of the day, a "shape" is just a word. Sure, [linguistic prescriptivism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linguistic_prescription) exists, but semantical talks aren't a good fit for BSE…